# Capybara rspec - attach file to hidden file_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I've got below form:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :document_type, value: item %>
<%= f.label :file, 'Upload', class: "btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm custom-btn-sm", id: "upload_kyc_#{idx}", name: "upload_button" %>
<%= f.file_field :file, class: "inputfile", accept: "jpeg, .jpg, .png, .pdf", onchange: 'this.form.requestSubmit()' %>
```

`custom_styles.scss`

```
.inputfile {
    width: 0.1px;
    height: 0.1px;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Which produces me in the browser:

[image]

Now I want to test this using Capybara. So what I did was:

```
def pdf_path
  "#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/files/sample.pdf"
end

it 'show message' do
  login_as user
  visit profile_path

  attach_file('upload_kyc_0', pdf_path, visible: true)
end
```

But I gets an error:

```
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find file field "inputfile" that is not disabled within #<Capybara::Node::Element tag="div" path="/HTML/BODY[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[2]">
```

How to submit that file then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass a block to `attach_file` with the actions the user would take to upload

```
attach_file(pdf_path) do
  find(:label, 'Upload').click
end
```

Answer (score 0):

With:

```
attach_file('upload_kyc_0', pdf_path, visible: true)`
```

you're trying to attach to the label, not to the file input. It should be:

```
attach_file('file', pdf_path, visible: true)
```

Comment: Same error type: `Capybara::ElementNotFound:
      Unable to find visible file field "file" that is not disabled`